# Extending and Embedding PHP and php 5.1.0

Tags: php

I am currently reading a book: Extending and Embedding PHP.
I have Ubuntu 16 . The book wants:
`./configure` <--- worked.
But with "make all install" I get a error message:

```
movic/Downloads/php-5.1.0/ext/dom/documenttype.c -o ext/dom/documenttype.lo 
 /home/tomovic/Downloads/php-5.1.0/meta_ccld -Iext/dom/ -I/home/tomovic/Downloads/php-5.1.0/ext/dom/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/home/tomovic/Downloads/php-5.1.0/include -I/home/tomovic/Downloads/php-5.1.0/main -I/home/tomovic/Downloads/php-5.1.0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/home/tomovic/Downloads/php-5.1.0/ext/date/lib -I/home/tomovic/Downloads/php-5.1.0/TSRM -I/home/tomovic/Downloads/php-5.1.0/Zend -D_REENTRANT -g -O2 -pthread -Wall -DZTS -c /home/tomovic/Downloads/php-5.1.0/ext/dom/documenttype.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o ext/dom/.libs/documenttype.o
/home/tomovic/Downloads/php-5.1.0/ext/dom/documenttype.c: In function 'dom_documenttype_internal_subset_read':
/home/tomovic/Downloads/php-5.1.0/ext/dom/documenttype.c:219:42: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'xmlBuf {aka struct _xmlBuf}'
    strintsubset = xmlStrndup(buff->buffer->content, buff->buffer->use);
                                          ^
Makefile:408: die Regel für Ziel „ext/dom/documenttype.lo“ scheiterte
make: *** [ext/dom/documenttype.lo] Fehler 1
root@DELL:~/Downloads/php-5.1.0#
```

Comment: The first, and obvious, question, why do you use php 5.1? It was released about 12 years ago and they stopped supporting it 11 years ago.

Comment: Yes I know. This is an old version, but my book is based on this version.
Please help me.

Comment: Then you need to get a new book.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It is rather an installation question. Please find the correct place to post your question. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because PHP 5.1 was end-of-lifed over a decade ago and is ludicrously insecure as a result.

Comment: Just do `sudo apt-get install php7.0` and you can start playing with PHP right away.

Answer (score 2):

Throw that book out and find another one.

PHP 5.1 is *completely* obsolete -- it was released in 2005, and has not been supported since the release of PHP 5.2 in November 2006. Due to changes in various libraries, it can no longer be compiled on modern Linux systems. Moreover, PHP has gone through a number of internal changes over the last 12 years, and much of the advice in that book is likely to be inaccurate today.

For an up-to-date look at PHP internals, refer to the [PHP at the Core: A Hacker's Guide](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.php) section of the PHP manual.

Comment: @ceejayoz In practice, support for PHP 5.1 continued a bit longer than that page claims. 24 Aug 2006 was the release date for PHP 5.1.6 -- clearly PHP 5.1 was supported on/after that date, unless we imagine that the developers threw up their hands and dropped all support for PHP 5 until they could get 5.2 out the door in November. :)